# Why are Google Analytics views inaccurate/bugged?

Tags: google-analytics

I have created a view to collect the domain name in the reports as well as the path.

I used Google guides to do that and it works as expected.

My problem is that when I click on reports and try to see the stats in the past few days, it's disappearing most of the time. I usually see the traffic coming in on the same day, but sometimes I completely lose that data on the 2nd or the 3rd day.

Here is an example: I was collecting traffic through this view since the 11th of April. I am displaying an Audience report that shows traffic from the 11th:

[image]

I have a few other views set up, some have 0 filters but show the same exact chart. What's even more strange is that if I change the time interval from the 22nd to the 21st it shows the following:

[image]

Basically from the 0 views on the 21st went up to 272 views, just by changing the timeframe.

However, if you check what the All Site data (default view) shows, it's completely different for the whole time - and this is what really happened:

[image]

What is the reason behind GA is hiding/changing the results even though I have NO filters applied to the views? It seems to be completely random what data it shows.

Also as I mentioned, if I check other views, even ones with no filters, no settings, etc it shows something completely different to the Default View (and yes they have been set up since the 11th of April).

Am I doing something wrong, or is this an expected behavior or bug?

Comment: Perhaps this question is a duplicate of [Why is Google Analytics data off when selecting multiple days?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/26045/why-is-google-analytics-data-off-when-selecting-multiple-days) Have you considered the unique visitors in the different time periods?

Comment: @JanineWhite I can confirm that this is *not* a duplicate at all. What the person in your referred question says is completely different from my problem. My problem is that no matter what timeframes I'm selecting, I'm getting different results. Also, my users are 100% unique users, they come from paid advertising.

Comment: I closed this question because nowadays questions about Google Analytics are better suited for [webmasters.se].

Answer (score 0):

This question appears to be a duplicate of [Why is Google Analytics data off when selecting multiple days?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/26045/why-is-google-analytics-data-off-when-selecting-multiple-days) The unique visitors in the different time periods are expected to vary based on the time period selected because only unique visitors are counted.  The larger the time period selected, the more likely a visit will not be counted because it is more likely to not be unique. Also, people are likely to visit the same site around the same time periods, so you are likely to pick up or drop counted visits depending on how you change the dates bounding your date filter.

Comment: This is not a duplicate question. What you're talking about is not my problem. My visitors are 100% unique and they come from different sites every day. Also, if you look at the Full View, it shows everything correctly, so what you say doesn't make any sense at all..